# React tic-tac-toe tutorial calculateWinner: function vs method

Tags: reactjs

In the React tic-tac-toe tutorial `calculateWinner` is defined as a function. Why not define it as a method inside the `Board` component? Are there any pros and cons?

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      squares: squares,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    });
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
    let status;
    if (winner) {
      status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
    } else {
      status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: [idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: you should probably ask this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In object oriented programming, functions are conceptually the same as methods. In this case, you are referring to "in-class methods", which means functions that are capable to directly utilize class variables.

Whether or not to have `calculateWinner` as a function outside of the class (by the way class is just a syntactic sugar in JS, it is essentially a function) depends on your programming design.

If you wish to have the board class to have a functionality of calculating the winner, which means no matter where you create a board object, you can calculate the winner based on its inner data structures; Then it would be much better for you to include `calculateWinner` as an in-class method.